# Which query to use to find closest items to a lat, long pair using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, proximity

I have clients (mobile and web) who can request nearest groups to them by providing a lat, lng pair.

Here's a basic snippet of my query, and I am not sure which one I should use for finding nearest groups.  I believe the 2nd one would be easier for me to use for keyset pagination, but anyway here they are:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  groups
ORDER BY
  groups.geography <-> st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-122.057608, 37.37761), 4326)
```

OR

```
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  groups
WHERE st_dwithin(groups.geography, st_setsrid(st_makepoint(-122.057608, 37.37761), 4326), 5000)
```

Which approach would be better to use to find the nearest results in order?

The second one is not ordered though, but the documentation says to use st_dwithin for finding results within a range of a lat, lng.

Comment: it seems there is much to clarify about many of the underlying concepts. simply speaking, you probably want to actually *combine* radius search with distance ordering. as it stands, though, both queries above, for themselves or combined, would probably not yield correct results. what is the tables CRS, what data type is stored (i.e. *geography* or *geometry*) and what geometry type are those groups (e.g. *POINT*)? did you set up a spatial index?

Comment: Hey.  Thanks for the reply.  I'm still learning how to use post GIS, so please forgive my lack of knowledge - basically applying what I am reading in the documentation.  

I am storing `geography` type in a column `geography`, and it is created using `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($5::decimal, $4::decimal), $6)` with values `long, lat, and 4326`.  

I have not yet set up a spatial index because I am still building this out so I don't have much data besides test data.

Comment: wasn't meant as teacherly as it sounded...,) using *geography* type, your queries do make more sense (one thing being the radius value you used for ST_DWithin; if it wasn't for *geography* type, units of *EPSG:4326* were in degrees). however, there are some subtletlies to know, the docs on ST_Distance and the KNNs cover those quite well; for instance, `<->` is meant to use an index (it will work without, though). An answer here would probably need to dig into the details of those subtletlies, with the simple conclusion: add the `ORDER BY ...` block to the second query...

Comment: No worries!  I appreciate it actually.  Thanks a lot, I think I am learning a lot more haha.  I was able to order by `st_distance`, :D